# Devise doesn't login in Google Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, ssl, nginx, devise

I'm working on user authentication in a Ruby on Rails web app using Devise gem. The process with very straight forward.

However, after adding Nginx and ssl certificate, the application I'm able to login in Mozilla Firefox but unable to login in Google Chrome. The only trace I can find, so far, is these few lines in my environment log file:

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"<some token>==", "user"=>{"email"=>"email@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"LOG IN"}
HTTP Origin header (https://<domain name>) didn't match request.base_url (: https://<domain name>:80)
```

My Nginx configuration for `/`

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto: $scheme;
 }
```

***Note:*** If I remove `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto: $scheme;` from `/etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf` The error in log file changes to:

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"<some token>==", "user"=>{"email"=>"email@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"LOG IN"}
HTTP Origin header (https://<domain name>) didn't match request.base_url (http://<domain name>:3000)
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I temporarly modified `actionpack` gem.

In `lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb` inside `actionpack` gem directory I updated:

```
def valid_request_origin? # :doc:
    if forgery_protection_origin_check
      # We accept blank origin headers because some user agents don't send it.
      request.origin.nil? || request.origin == request.base_url
    else
      true
    end
  end
```

to be:

```
def valid_request_origin? # :doc:
    if forgery_protection_origin_check
      # We accept blank origin headers because some user agents don't send it.
      request.origin.nil? || request.origin == request.base_url || request.base_url == ": https://<domain name>:80"
    else
      true
    end
  end
```